# Dynamic Table Rows

Tags: html, css

I have four cells on one table and another table with about eight
cells.

I have set the max-width to 300px on all cells. Now the problem I face
is that the cells do not drop to a second row if the page is too
small. (Which is in every matter at the moment haha)

I was wondering how I would go about adding dynamic rows to make the extra content beyond the page width, drop below into a new row?

All the code can be seen in the Developers tools for the following [website](http://www.splicepro.com.au)

(Cells/Rows in the products section is the problem I am facing.)

Kind regards,
Jesse M.

Comment: Its simple, dont use Table, but Divs. You shouldnt use tables for other things than real tables. So your menu should by `ul li`, and other parts should by divs, sections ...
Tables was used in the 90s, but now its 2016

Comment: Dont use table, you can check how the bootstrap grid works and do the same

Comment: `<table>` tag is only for tabulated data purposes. Don't use it for layouts. You can achieve the same behaviour with `<div>` and CSS `display: table | table-row | table-cell`

Comment: Sweet. I've used DIV's before and it has worked with previous websites however I thought that tables might work better. Seems not haha Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Ohh my sweet summer child</s>,

The `<table>` element is "designed" to behave that way. The `table` will try to cramp up all the columns in the possible space and based on various `css` and `html` attributes, hide/overflow/cramp-up the data in columns, But **never** will it allow the columns of one row to flow down to another row.

So you are left with a lot of options using CSS and HTML elements.

If you are into frameworks, I recommend Bootstrap that is designed to work exactly that way, and use the provided `col-xx-x` classes for the elements that need to be in a row at some screen width, and "drop below into a new row" on other screen width.